# Use Facebook login credentials to sign in/up to my application

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, facebook-graph-api, response

I'm using Facebooks' API to get user credentials to login/sign-up to my application.

But I'm struggling with what type of credentials should I save to the database as username(email) and password? should I save Facebook's user-id and token as username and password? or is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add new field and name it as facebook_id(bigint):

1. on sign in/up flow you will get facebook token from client.
2. you need to request to facebook api for get user profile from token.
3. after it success you will get some basic info like (user_id, full_name, email, user_profile, etc). then you can do login.

you can do validate exist email or user_id from facebook depend on your requirement.

hope it can give you some idea and also i'm not a native speaker.

Comment: What should I store in the password field? I mean I can't store any of this public info (id, name email) there should be something that nobody knows except Facebook

Comment: There are many approach. if you want your user to login with many social. i would suggest create new table that have with 3 fields (user_id, provider_type, provider_id) which link with user.

Comment: if we implement login with social. password should be nullable. but we do validate from code.

Comment: isn't it risky to set password field to nullable?

Comment: This case you need to validate at backend when login with email/password.

Comment: Validate what? can you please explain

Comment: the login email/password process we required email/password. after we got email we will query user. if have user we will compare hash user input password to compare with our hash password in db.

Comment: so you just need to validate that user must input email and password for password login. and social login when you compare provider_id from social. that it

Answer (score 1):

Check this package:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/socialite

It provides social authentication out of the box for laravel including facebook login.

Comment: I decided to use after all but it's still a struggle trying to find what should password field contain :P